# Custom Helper with jQuery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've created a custom helper element with the jQuery UI sortable component.

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        helper: function() {
            return $('<tr style="background-color:Fuscia"><td colspan="5" ><table><tr><td class="ui-state-default" style="background-color:Red">[XXXXXXXXXXXX]</td></tr><tr><td colspan="5" class="ui-state-default" style="background-color:Red">[XXXXXXXXXXXX]</td></tr></table></td></tr>');
        },
    });
    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

The custom element does in fact appear when I'm dragging an item. However, it overflows the "dragging box" that is apparently a container for whatever is being dragged.

I've posted my code and markup at http://jsfiddle.net/LpyXh/.

Can someone see what I'm missing?

Comment: So are you just wanting to get rid of the containing element so all you see is the Red boxes with the Xs?

Comment: Yes, or at the very least, make the containing element big enough to enclose the red boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified the height of each tr, which is being applied to the helper.

http://jsfiddle.net/LpyXh/3/

Will fix the container.

Comment: Hmm... I'm actually having trouble seeing exactly where you changed it. I've compared your code to mine but missed it. Where am I setting the height of each tr and your code doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

In the CSS add

```
.ui-sortable-helper
{
   background:none;    
   border:none;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LpyXh/2/

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility. Still testing.